# LDO phase margin

Tags: ldo, stability, phase-margin

The recommended phase margin to achieve stability is 45. With a positive phase margin, but less than 45, the system is stable, but the output has some oscillation. For LDOs, we have specifications for overvoltage and undervoltage due to transient load regulation. If we choose a positive phase margin but less than 45 and the maximum overshoot of the oscillation does not exceed the transient load regulation specification, can we consider the system stable even if the phase margin is 10 for example (and in Monte Carlo the phase margin does not become negative)?

Comment: LDOs are fairly non-linear devices.  The phase margin tends to be worse at lower load currents. However if the transient performance over all conditions is OK with you at the worst-case phase margin I suppose you could say it's usable.

Comment: Phase margin affects the transient response: a low phase margin (30-45°) leads to a nervous but potentially-overshooting system while a stronger phase margin (70-90°) brings a longer recovery time but without overshoot. If you run a worst-case exercise with your LDO, the phase margin should never be lower than 30°.